# Why do I receive an error message while trying to access some of my GNOME shell extension settings?

Tags: 18.04, error-handling, gnome-shell-extension, javascript, clutter

Some of my GNOME shell extensions don't let me configure their features because I receive an error message when I try to open them. The following image is what I see when I try to open the configurations of the "*Web Search Dialog*" extension:

[image]

The message in the white box is this one:

```
Error: Requiring Clutter, version none: Typelib file for namespace 'Clutter' (any version) not found

Stack trace:
  @/home/ramuyko/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/web_search_dialog@awamper.gmail.com/utils.js:17:7
  @/home/ramuyko/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/web_search_dialog@awamper.gmail.com/prefs.js:26:7
  _getExtensionPrefsModule@resource:///org/gnome/shell/extensionPrefs/main.js:75:13
  wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
  _selectExtension@resource:///org/gnome/shell/extensionPrefs/main.js:90:31
  wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
  _onCommandLine@resource:///org/gnome/shell/extensionPrefs/main.js:243:17
  wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
  main@resource:///org/gnome/shell/extensionPrefs/main.js:397:5
  @<main>:1:43
```

I think this error is not an isolated problem of the "Web Search Dialog" extension because I receive this same kind of error with other extensions as well (like with the configurations of the "*HowDoI*" extension). **Does anyone know why it happens and if there's an easy workaround to solve this issue?**

---

PS1: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with GNOME Shell 3.28.1.

PS2: Although I can't configure its features, the *GNOME shell extensions* with this kind of error are working fine. The only problem is accessing their configuration.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found a solution to this issue on [this GitHub page](https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/issues/398). Basically, the problem is that some of the dependencies of the **Clutter library** are missing on Ubuntu (mine is 18.04 and the guy on GitHub is using 16.10). Just installing the following packages solves the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-clutter-1.0 gir1.2-clutter-gst-3.0 gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0
```

Comment: This still applies to 18.10 and likely will to 19.04, thank you!

Comment: I have a similar issue for a different package, with the difference that it doesn't say `(any version)` but version `2`. The packages you provided didn't solve the problem... what packages would I need to install in this case?

Comment: Applies for 19.10 too